# Where to get regression treatment effect instead of average treatment effect after using propensity scoring match

Tags: stata, matching

In Dehejia and Wahba (2002), after the average treatment effect column, there is also a new column "regression treatment effect". I know the average treatment effect is just the average difference of the treated and the matched controlled outcome. I am not sure what the regression treatment is supposed to be and how can I obtain it from Stata.

Comment: You need to use a purposeful strategy.  See for example BBR chapter 17: http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html

Comment: Minimal name and date references should (please) be fleshed out as if giving a journal reference in a paper or dissertation (or, if more appropriate, a stable URL). You shouldn't assume that people are familiar with the literature you know.

Comment: Correct link: https://hbiostat.org/bbr

Answer (score 2):

On page 154 of D&W (2002)$^*$, it says

> In addition to using a **weighted** difference in means to estimate the
>   treatment effect, we also consider a **weighted** regression using the
>   treatment and matched comparison units, with the comparison units
>   **weighted** by the number of times that they are matched to a treated
>   unit. A regression can potentially improve the precision of the
>   estimates

This is a regression of the form

```
reg outcome_var i.treated age education ... if matched==1 [iw = weight_var]
```

---

$^*$ *Propensity Score-Matching Methods For Nonexperimental Causal Studies*
by Rajeev Dehejia and Sadek Wahba, *The Review of Economics and Statistics*, 2002, vol. 84, issue 1, 151-161